# Post request to selling partner API sandbox endpoint return InvalidSignature

Tags: ruby, amazon-mws

I'm currently trying to create a document and upload it to the SP-API sandbox environment using ruby and HTTP.rb gem. My steps are:

1. Request the LWA access token by a refresh token
2. Assume the role and request the STS token
3. Sign the request header using AWS::SignV4 SDK
4. Send the POST request to the endpoint `/feeds/2020-09-04/documents` with body `json: { 'contentType' => 'text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8' }`

However, SP-API keeps returning `"code": "InvalidSignature"` to me. But all my other 'GET' requests like get_orders, get_order_items are working correctly. 
Here is how I send my request:

```
@url = '/feeds/2020-09-04/documents'
@body = if sandbox
    { 'contentType' => 'text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8' }
 else
    { 'contentType' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8' }
 end
 @request_type = 'POST' 

response = http.headers(headers).send(@request_type.downcase.to_sym, request_url, json: @body)
```

Comment: I'm aware that it might be caused by the parameter/body in the request, it happened to me when I request orders in invalid time format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the AWS::Signer::V4 document, turns out I should pass the body into the signer as well.
`signer.sign_request(http_method: @request_type, url: request_url, body: @body)`

Answer (score 1):

I published the amz_sp_api rubygem that does this, but I would welcome a contribution of the ruby code for encrypting the feed submissions as required by SP-API: https://github.com/ericcj/amz_sp_api/issues/1